Is $N - \varphi(N)$ a square, if $N = q^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?
This question was inspired by this MSE question.
In MSE, it is shown that
$$n - \varphi(n) = (2^{p-1})^2$$
if $n = {2^{p-1}}(2^p - 1)$ is an even perfect number.
Here is my question in this post:

Is $N - \varphi(N)$ a square, if $N = q^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?


MY ATTEMPT
Note that
$$N - \varphi(N) = q^k m^2 - \varphi(q^k) \varphi(m^2) = q^k m^2 - (q^k - q^{k-1})(m\varphi(m)) = q^{k-1} m (qm - (q - 1)\varphi(m)).$$
Since the Eulerian form $N = q^k m^2$ of an odd perfect number dictates that $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we test whether
$$m (qm - (q - 1)\varphi(m))$$
is a square. Suppose otherwise.
Then
$$m (qm - (q - 1)\varphi(m)) = Q^2$$
which forces $q \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, since $\varphi(m)$ is always even. (Since $q$ is the special prime, this means that $q \geq 17$.)
Alas, this is where I get stuck.

This is likely a very tough question. Notice that if one could prove that $N-\phi(N)$ is a perfect square this would imply that $N$ is not 5 (mod 8), since $8|\phi(n)$. However, this would among other things, imply that 5 is not the special prime. Thus, it is very likely that proving this is well outside what current techniques can do.

Note also that the statement is at least false if the largest prime divisor of $N$ is not $q$. If the largest prime divisor is $p \neq q$, then $p^a||n$  for some even $n$. But $p^{a-1}|| n - \phi(n)$  and so $n$ is not a perfect square. So this would also force that the largest prime divisor of $n$ must be the special prime. Overall, it seems like a more productive direction to go in would be to try and show that $n - \phi(n)$ is NOT a perfect square, but I don't see any obvious way to do that either.

@JoshuaZ: I appreciate your comment, Josh! I was hoping someone with more experience on the Euler totient function would be able to settle this one. (This question was mainly triggered by an inquiry that I received via e-mail.)
